# How to use for loop to read csv one at time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string todate = txtToDate1.Text;
string fromtime = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
string totime = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;

string fromdatetime = fromdate + "_" + fromtime;
string todatetime = todate + "_" + totime;


con.ConnectionString = constr;

//create instance for command object 
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();


cmd.Connection = con;   
// set your file name in the below query
cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + fromdatetime + ".csv ";



//Open Oledb Connection to read CSV file 
con.Open(); 

//Create one datatable to store data from CSV file
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// Load Data into the datatable 
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

string fromdatetime is something like 12162013_0730.csv and string todatetime is something like 12162013_0930.csv...how can i use for loop to read the file in between the fromdatetime todatetime... read 12162013_0730.csv ,12162013_0830.csv,12162013_0930.csv, one file at a time?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: i need a for loop something like 


For(fromdatetime todatetime +1hour)
{
cmd.commandtext( getting csv file from 0730 t0 0930
}


i need for loop do read csv file one by one 0730,0830,0930

Comment: And your current code, does it worked to read from one .csv file?

Comment: yes it work only for single file..

Answer (score 1):

if your current code works fine then somthing like the following would do the job

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact("09162014_0830", "MMddyyyy_hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact("11162014_0830", "MMddyyyy_hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

               con.open()
               var dt = new DataTable();
               while (start <= end)
               {
                   string csvname = start.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmm")+".csv";
                   cmd.CommandText = "select * from " + csvname ;
                   var tempdt = new DataTable();
                   tempdt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                   dt.Merge(tempdt);
                   start = start.AddHours(1d);
               }
               con.close()
```

and now the dt holds all the data in your csv files between those dates, make sure you handle exceptions.

Comment: but im using "select count...." to count the pass value...how to actually to show it different columns of one table..like on 09162014 i got 50pass , on 10162014 i got 60 pass...

Comment: @user3145376 i am not sure what do you mean , its better to ask a new more detailed question.